# Loading mysql calls into arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Normally have not had to do this alot but my process didn't seem to work correctly this time so I am asking for some clarification

This works for a single item in the query:

```
    $query="SELECT data1 as product FROM Products ORDER BY Title"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query)
        or die("Query failed -".$query);        
    $rows=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
```

As I said this works fine for a single item being returned all of the items returned in the query end up in an array called $rows

```
    $query="SELECT data1 as product, data2 as info FROM Products ORDER BY Title"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query)
        or die("Query failed -".$query);        
    $i=0;
    $data1=array();
    $data2=array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
        $data1[$i] = $row[0];
        $data2[$i++] = $row[1];
    }
```

This does not seem to do the same thing or I missed something.

Am I missing something? 
If not then I need to look at something else as my issue but need to make sure about this.

The result I desire is two arrays one containing the all of first items from the query result and the second array containing all of the second items from the query result.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: I would suggest using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), as the old [mysql_ functions are being depreciated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). PDO has a [query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) method of its own with an example of what you want to do in that link.

Comment: @Stu 'deprecated'. 'depreciated' means something else.

Comment: i recommend using `$row['product']` and `$row['info']` inside your `while` loop so it's much easier to know what the hell you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$row = array();
while($row[] = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {}
```

And, as already stated, use mysqli or PDO. mysql_* has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query="SELECT data1 as product, data2 as info FROM Products ORDER BY Title"; 
$result = mysql_query($query)
    or die("Query failed -".$query);        
$i=0;
$data1=array();
$data2=array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $data1[$i] = $row[0];
    $data2[$i] = $row[1];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: if you're going to do that, you don't need `$i` at all. just push items into the arrays like: `$data[] = $row[0]`, etc